# Emulating EMBM on modern hardware

Tags: emulation

I wonder if it is possible to emulate *Environment-Mapped Bump Mapping* on modern hardware (nVidia's GeForce). This feature is native for very old Matrox G400 card and is no longer supported in any known to me card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, someone pointed me out that I should write hooks for Direct3D 6.1 dll that will replace calls for EMBM with vertex shaders. So question can be closed